# Step-up power supply for motor

Tags: motor, amperage, step-up

I know very little about electricity.  I am a private detective.  I am converting on older surveillance periscope to modern IP cameras. The periscope has several motors that raise/lower turn 360% and on the tilts the periscope mirror up and down.  These were all wired to a 16 pin cord that also included communication.  I am removing everything back to the motors. One motor is a (Pittman 9234S006-R1 Servo motor, 24VDC, 6151rpm no load, 5.17oz/in tor const, .16/8.11A )  The van is 12 volt dc with a 12 volt panel and 120 volt ac inverter.  I want to add a 24 volt step up power supply for this motor.  I obviously want 24 volt dc power but I don't understand the amps or watts.  Can anyone explain this to me?  Is more watts and amps better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Thanks so output amps is not a concern, the motor will take what it wants!  What about watts?  Any concern?   Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description I assume there are 4 motors, 23W each. Although it would be logical to get the power supply to cover the maximum power needed, it's often unnecessary. The real power draw of the motor depends on the load it experiences, in periscope, it probably won't be much. If I had to guess probably around 12W or less.

If you plan on simultaneously using all of the motors take around 50-60W power supply, if only one motor at the time will be used then 20W will suffice.
It's a good practice to take power supply about 20-30% stronger then the typical power draw.

As to how does "amps and watts work?"
The simplified version is that:
Volts - How fast the motor will spin.
Amps - How much force it will apply on the shaft.
Watts - The power of the motor = product of force and speed (Volts x Amps).
More amps and watts id generally better, just bare in mind that the bigger the disproportion in maximum delivered vs used power, the lower the efficiency of the converter

A cheap option is to go with something like this, but there is risk that the output may vary from what is in datasheet.
[https://www.amazon.com/Converter-Regulator-Adapter-Vehicle-DC9-20V/dp/B01EFUHFW6/ref=sr_1_19?keywords=12v%2Bto%2B24v%2Bconverter&qid=1705505615&sr=8-19&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EFUHFW6)

Comment: It has only one motor that is 24v two others that are 12V  Thank for this clarification.